# Reading credentials from another file doesn't work in Python

Tags: python, python-import, credentials

I created a Python file called pw.py where I store my username and password.

The content of pw.py is as follows:

```
username = "username1"
password = "pswrd2"
```

To access these credentials from another file called ProducerReddit.ipynb, I do the following:

```
from pw import password, username
```

However, when I try to print password and username, they are always empty.
The two files are inside the same folder.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're importing the right `pw` module? (`import pw; print(pw)`)

Comment: Yes I double-checked. What I did is I created a new file with a different name than pw and now it works. I have no explanation!!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to check do you have a `__init__.py` file in the your top folder.
If you don't have please create this `__init__.py` module.
Then try to use absolute import path.
For example you have top directorty with this structure:

```
top_directory:
              __init__.py
              pw.py
              other_file.py
```

your import instructions in the other_file.py shoud be like this:

```
from top_directory.pw import username, password
```

I hope this may help you